# What is the 'dt' argument in functions supposed to represent?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I see that `dt` is often used in function arguments, e.g., `CCScheduler.update(dt)`.

Does anyone know what it's supposed to represent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes. Some programmers' favorite passtime: abbreviate every variable until only they understand the meaning through conditioned memory.

`dt` stands for "delta time". It means the time passed since the last call to the same method. In layman's terms "delta" simply means "difference".

In game engines delta time usually refers to the time passed since the last frame was rendered. It is defined mathematically as:

```
deltaTime = timeNow - timeOfPreviousCallToMethod;
```

To understand why this is used and how to use it and how probably not to use it in iOS games read my [blog post about delta time](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/10/game-engine-multiply-delta-time-or-not/).